# Velocity #foreach with XmlTool node list with text nodes

Tags: java, templates, dom, foreach, velocity

I'm trying to write a Velocity template that makes use of a DOM object. In particular my dependencies are Velocity 1.7 and Velocity-tools 2.0. 
Following the documentation, this is how I pass the DOM to the template engine:

```
XmlTool tool = new XmlTool().parse(xmlString);
VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();
context.put("xml", tool);
...
```

Let's say that this is my original XML document:

```
<root>
    <foo>
        <bar>
            <baz>10</baz>
            <qux>NO</qux>
        </bar>
        <bar>
            <baz>20</baz>
            <qux>YES</qux>
        </bar>
        <bar>
            <baz>30</baz>
            <qux>NO</qux>
        </bar>
    </foo>
</root>
```

And this my template file:

```
#if($xml.foo)
<document>
    #foreach($bar in $xml.foo)
    <repeatableElement>
        <aaa>$bar.baz.text</aaa>
        <bbb>$bar.qux.text</bbb>
    </repeatableElement>
    #end
</document>
```

Now my problem is, if I run this, the output looks like:

```
<document>
    <repeatableElement>
        <aaa>102030</aaa>
        <bbb>NOYESNO</bbb>
    </repeatableElement>
    <repeatableElement>
        <aaa>102030</aaa>
        <bbb>NOYESNO</bbb>
    </repeatableElement>
    <repeatableElement>
        <aaa>102030</aaa>
        <bbb>NOYESNO</bbb>
    </repeatableElement>
</document>
```

As you can see, the `#foreach` loop correctly prints one `repeatableElement` for each `$bar` object. However the `.text` method on `$bar` children concatenates the text nodes of the siblings too! 
What I want instead is to access each leaf text node alone:

```
<repeatableElement>
    <aaa>10</aaa>
    <bbb>NO</bbb>
</repeatableElement>
<repeatableElement>
    <aaa>20</aaa>
    <bbb>YES</bbb>
</repeatableElement>
...
```

Any tip is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known problem of the Tools 2.0 XmlTool, whose getters call the JDOM method `getPath()` instead of `getUniquePath()`. So `$bar.baz` returns all  nodes.

To circumvent this problem, you can directly use the underlying JDOM API:

```
#if($xml.foo)
<document>
    #foreach($bar in $xml.foo.children())
    <repeatableElement>
        <aaa>$bar.node().element('baz').text</aaa>
        <bbb>$bar.node().element('qux').text</bbb>
    </repeatableElement>
    #end
</document>
#end
```

(Also note that you should loop on `$xml.foo.children()`).